# Serializer Dealing with nested objects

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Using the [Django REST framework](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers.html) I have the following Serializer below. I would like to add in (nested) related objects (ProductCatSerializer) to ProductSerializer. I have tried the following....

```
class ProductCatSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ProductCat
        fields = ('id', 'title')

class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Serializing the Product instances into representations.
    """
    ProductCat = ProductCatSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'description', 'price',)
```

So what I want to happen is Products to show its related category nested in the results.

Thank you.

**Update:**

Using the depth = 2 option *(thanks Nandeep Mali )* I  now get the nested values, but they only show using ID's and not keyparis like the rest of the json request (see category below). Its almost right.

```
"results": [
        {
            "id": 1, 
            "title": "test ", 
            "description": "test", 
            "price": "2.99", 
            "product_url": "222", 
            "product_ref": "222", 
            "active": true, 
            "created": "2013-02-15T15:49:28Z", 
            "modified": "2013-02-17T13:05:28Z", 
            "category": [
                1, 
                2
            ],
```

Comment: Shouldn't the model in `ProductCatSerializer` be something else? As an aside, your name is really in sync with the question.

Comment: Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753359/serializing-foreign-key-objects-in-django

Comment: sorry just a mistake when typing the example, dow! corrected. Name yes lol :)

Comment: @Nandeep Mali i'm trying to so this within http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers.html

Comment: Oh yes. Not very familiar with that framework. They do have nested support though: http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers.html#specifiying-nested-serialization What is the issue that you had? Have you used the `depth = 1` setting?

Comment: yes just stumbling to understand how I relate this with above.

Comment: well I'll be how did i miss the option depth = 1!!!!!!!!!! only gives me the ID pks tho but seems to work on the models. now if I can just workout how to show the name with keypairs

Comment: If you have figured out the answer it would be helpful to write it as an answer :)

Comment: yep, i now have a different question. you solved this one:)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your example was almost right, except that you should call the field 'productcat' (or whatever the model relationshipt is called, but without the CamelCase), and add it to your fields.

```
class ProductCatSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ProductCat
        fields = ('id', 'title')

class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Serializing the Product instances into representations.
    """
    productcat = ProductCatSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'description', 'price', 'productcat')
```

Comment: perfect, I'm learning, slowly, but learning! Thank you again Tom.

Comment: 'productcat' will be an object. What if we need to add 'productcat' elements as normal field name along with 'title','description'