# Django follow value foreign key in ajax json

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, django

MY VIew

```
def cargar_categorias(request):
    data = serializers.serialize("json", MyModel.objects.all())
    return HttpResponse(data,  mimetype='aplication/json')
```

response json

```
[{"pk": 8, "model": "MyModel.MyModel", "fields": {"celular": "234342342", "logo": "recetas/aurelio.jpg", "tipo": 1, ....
```

but the field "tipo" is a foreign Key, I need recover the value of this field and not the id (1)

My Jquery code

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json; charset-utf-8",
    dateType: "json",
    url: "/cargar_categorias",
    success: function(response){
        var i=(response.length-1)-6;
        for( i;i<=(response.length-1);i++){
            $('#locations').append("<li data-celular='"
                    + response[i].fields.celular +"' data-tipo='"
                    + response[i].fields.tipo +"'><img  href=#" 
                    + response[i].fields.logo +" src='/media/"
                    + response[i].fields.logo +"'/></li>");
            }
        }
    });
```

I think can use select_related() but not work, or response[i].fields.tipo.nombre or ....
I don't now, please help me, this going crazy, sorry my english

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3753769/1566605

Answer (score 1):

One potential way around this is to construct your own dictionary object based on the returns of a queryset. You'd do something like this:

```
queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
list = [] #create list
    for row in queryset: #populate list
        list.append({'celular':row.celular, 'logo': row.logo, 'tipo': row.tipo.id})
    list_json = json.dumps(list) #dump list as JSON
    return HttpResponse(list_json, 'application/javascript')
```