# How to serialize models in Django?

Tags: python, json, django, api, serialization

I have pretty simple and obvious question that i am trying to search for a while now.

I have a model, `Picture`, that has foreign keys like `created_by`, `Province`, and `City`.

#### What I want is to get all model fields serialized to `json`.

Models.py:

```
class Picture(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField("Title", max_length=10000, null=True, blank=True)
    meta_data = models.TextField("meta_data", null=True, blank=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="created_by")
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, null=True, blank=True)
    pro = models.ForeignKey(Province, verbose_name="Province")


class Province(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    pi_meta_data = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    intro = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=10000, null=True, blank=True)


class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    pi_meta_data = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    intro = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=10000, null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: Have you tried to pass column names to `queryset.values()`? I know that idea of "magically generating" is quite attractive, but not very usable in a real world. I'm using specific DTO factories that produces simple dictionaries or list of dictionaries; eg. `def pictures_list_dto_factory(picture_queryset)` or/and `def picture_details_dto_factory(picture_instance)`. You can easily serialize output from these factories, for example using `json.dumps`. If this is not a solution for you, please provide more details about your use case.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Django Rest Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/), and [serialize](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization#using-modelserializers) models with ease.

Your model serializers would be:

```
class PicturesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Picture
        # Only including fields in this case to explicitly show that 
        # every field in the Pictures model is serialized. In the rest of 
        # the Serializes fields will be left out for brevity.
        fields = ("name", "meta_data", "created_by", "city", "pro")

class ProvinceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Province


class CitySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = City
```

#### *Thats it.* Seriously.

Everything is nicely packed into json for you, even if you change your models down the line.

But how easy is it to use the serialized data? A simple view using those serialized models would be:

```
class PicturesList(APIView):
    """
    List all Pictures, or create a new Picture.
    """
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        pictures = Pictures.objects.all()
        serializer = PicturesSerializer(pictures, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = PicturesSerializer(data=request.DATA)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

The documentation is literally amazing. They have a cool [tutorial](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart) to get you started. They even have a sweet [browseable api](http://restframework.herokuapp.com/) that lets you visually navigate through your api.

Comment: I really like the answer and the code simplicity. but my question remains. 

I want to get foreign key data. like picture = pic.name, pic.created_by.name, pic.created_by.id, pic.created_by.email.

Comment: @user570826 The foreign key fields in Picture are all serialized in the PictureSerializer as well! Do you want the reverse relationship in the other models?

Comment: @user570826 ie. The fields serialized in the PictureSerializer are name, meta_data, created_by, city, and pro.

Answer (score 0):

There is a "Django Full Serialization" module which is part of wadofstuff which can serialize related objects among other things. This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/3753769/187729 has more info.