# Serialize Django queryset with foreign values

Tags: json, django, django-queryset, django-serializer

I am working with Django 1.7 and I have this models

```
class Producto(models.Model):
    item = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    unidad = models.CharField(max_length=5)    
    usuario = models.ForeignKey(User)
    alta = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    imagen = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/producto/',blank=True,null=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.item

class OEntrada(models.Model):
    folio = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    codigo_proveedor = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    nombre_proveedor = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    status = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    fecha = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.folio

class OEntradaDetalle(models.Model):
    oentrada = models.ForeignKey(OEntrada,related_name='detalles')
    producto = models.ForeignKey(Producto)
    cantidad_ordenada = models.DecimalField(default=0,decimal_places=2, max_digits=10)
    cantidad_recibida = models.DecimalField(default=0,decimal_places=2, max_digits=10)
    fecha_entrega = models.DateField(blank=True,null=True)
    epc = models.CharField(max_length=25,null=True,blank=True)
```

Ang I want to make a JSON with some specific data with some filters, taking only the products that are NOT in the Inventory (I've got this)
I want to get the `oentrada.folio`, `producto.item`, `cantidad_recibida` and `epc` from `OEntradaDetalle`

I have tried annotate:

```
def producto_para_ingreso(request,folio_orden_entrada):
    inventario = Inventario.objects.all().values('epc')
    pendientes = OEntradaDetalle.objects.filter(oentrada__folio=folio_orden_entrada,
        cantidad_recibida__gt=0).exclude(epc__in=inventario).annotate(item='producto__item')
    response = serializers.serialize('json',pendientes)
    return HttpResponse(response)
```

also I've tried values: (this returns me what I want but in ugly format, like: `{producto__item: u'ITEM1',cantidad_recibida:Decimal('100')}` )

```
pendientes = OEntradaDetalle.objects.filter(
oentrada__folio=folio_orden_entrada,cantidad_recibida__gt=0
).exclude(epc__in=inventario).values(
'epc','producto__item','cantidad_recibida')
```

Actually this is what I have now: (JSON)

```
{
        "fields": {
            "producto": 7,
            "oentrada": 1,
            "epc": "122C00000829",
            "fecha_entrega": null,
            "cantidad_ordenada": "1",
            "cantidad_recibida": "1"
        },
        "model": "inventario_rfid.oentradadetalle_deferred_cantidad_ordenada_fecha_entrega_oentrada_id",
        "pk": 3
    },
```

and I need something like this:

```
{
    "fields": {
        "producto": "ITEM-1", <<I need a Foreign Value, not the ID
        "oentrada": "E01",    << Same in this, I need a Foreign Value not the Id
        "epc": "122C00000829",
        "fecha_entrega": null,
        "cantidad_ordenada": "1",
        "cantidad_recibida": "1"
    },
    "model": "inventario_rfid.oentradadetalle_deferred_cantidad_ordenada_fecha_entrega_oentrada_id",
    "pk": 3
},
```

It would be awsome if I can get a clean JSON, excluding the `fields, model and pk` info.

Thanks!!

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753359/serializing-foreign-key-objects-in-django) similar to you requirement, and if you are using for restful purpose , i suggest to use Django Rest Framework.

Comment: I saw it but I am using Django 1.7 and wadofstuff.django.serializers.json is not working anymore, also I've tried natural_key but have no luck

Comment: I am using Django Rest Framework as well, but, how can I accomplish this with REST?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in your serializers.py

```
class ProductoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Producto


class OEntradaDetalleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    producto = ProductoSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = OEntradaDetalle
        fields = ('producto', epc', ....)# write the field which you needed
```

Comment: I tried something like this but here's another detail... where I can put the 3 filter-conditions? I need the products of one `oentrada__folio` that have more than 0 in `cantidad_recibida` field AND that the `epc` is not registered in the Inventory (`filter(oentrada__folio=folio_orden_entrada,
        cantidad_recibida__gt=0).exclude(epc__in=inventario)`). This reasons make me go for a "more manual" option than the API's