# Django ajax response model

Tags: python, django, django-select-related

I need to get data in template.

I have ajax request:

```
$(".retailer-list-img").mouseover(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var category_id = $this.attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        'url': '/shop/getfeatured/',
        'method': 'POST',
        'data': {'category_id': category_id,},
        'success': function(response){
             console.log(response)
         }
    });
});
```

views.py

```
def MerchantGetfeaturedView(request):
    featured = Merchant.objects.filter(
        is_catalog_active=1,
        is_active=1,
        category_id=request.REQUEST.get('category_id'),
        date_deleted__isnull=True
    ).select_related('_image')

    featured = serializers.serialize('json', featured)

    return HttpResponse(featured, content_type="application/json")
```

But there is no related object "image"? How to serialize related model? 
Thanks.

Comment: your question isn't very clear. Can you post a traceback of your error?

Comment: please update the question to add models

Comment: I would personally avoid using the serializers for an AJAX request as it exposes information about your database structure that end-users don't need to know. You can use something like `featured =  json.dumps(list(featured.values('name','category_id','...')))`. Also, you may need to remove the underscore in `select_related("_image")`

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753359/serializing-foreign-key-objects-in-django

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to transform your object.

```
result = { 'is_catalog_active': featured['is_catalog_active']
           'is_active': 1,
           'category_id': int(request.REQUEST.get('category_id')),
           'image_id' : _image.id,
           'image_name': _image.name 
         }
```

You can have PyCharm to help you auto-complete related model field. Random guessing sometimes is bad, if you have right tool. Alternatively, check django document for further investigation.

Secondly,
 $.ajax() function don't have fail callback, so the pattern is not complete.
 In reality, user have to know front end feed back. e.g. which type of error.